# Loop to Display Multiple Records when Associated Column Equals ____

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm still a novice with PHP and MySQL but willing to learn and now I'm in need of help after three days of tinkering.

First, to help you understand my db structure, I have a MySQL db table named "o70vm_invoices_items" and I'm trying to loop through the results that are for each invoice_ID.  Each item in the items table has a PK (o70vm_invoices_items.id) and the invoice_ID column is a link to another table (invoices).

In the items table, for example, some invoices would have one item, others could have two or three items.  I'm feeling quite challenged with how to loop through to display all of the items (o70vm_invoices_items.name) associated with each invoice.

Here is my MySQL query statement:

```
$queryItems = "SELECT       
    o70vm_invoices_items.id AS 'Item_ID',
    o70vm_invoices_items.invoice_id AS 'Invoice_ID_on_Items',
    o70vm_invoices_items.name AS 'Program',
    o70vm_invoices_items.value AS 'Fee',
    o70vm_invoices_items.amount AS 'Qty',
    o70vm_invoices_items.desc AS 'forWeek',

    GROUP_CONCAT(o70vm_invoices_items.desc SEPARATOR ' & ') As 'forWeekGroup',          
    ROUND(SUM((o70vm_invoices_items.value)*(o70vm_invoices_items.amount)),2) AS 'INV-TOTAL'
    FROM o70vm_invoices_items
    WHERE o70vm_invoices_items.invoice_id = $invoiceID
    GROUP BY o70vm_invoices_items.invoice_id";
```

As you can see, I'm searching the results from INVOICE_ID.  This part works great.  I get these results to display easy.  The problem is I'm looking to display each value in the "o70vm_invoices_items.name" column for the selected  Invoice ID AND I can only display one item.

Here is my attempt to loop through the results and display the info:

```
// storing the result of this MySQL query
$resultItems = mysql_query($queryItems) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "<table><tr>";

while($rowItems = mysql_fetch_array($resultItems))
    {

    echo "<td>";                
    echo "<input type='text' title='' name='name' id='name' value='". $rowItems['Program']. "' /><br>";
    echo            "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr></table>";
```

Again, I can only get the result of one item, not all the items.  Any help, very much appreciated.  I think I may need a different way to write an Array perhaps.  Also, as you can see, I'm displaying it in a input tag that I am hoping I will later be able to EDIT the content.

PLEASE NOTE: Once I have this figured out, I will also need to do the same for Fee and Qty columns as well.

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_*` functions. As for the query, no need to put `o70vm_invoices_items.` everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I would rewrite the sql so that it appears easier to read, to do that assign an `alias` to the table and use that when referencing the fields. This is especially useful when you are joining multiple tables - each `alias` must be unique. In the case of your original sql because you are only drawing data from one table there is no need really for an alias nor to use the full table name as a prefix to the individual fields (ie: table.field ) - just the fieldname would have sufficed.

```
<?php
    $queryitems = "select 
            o.`id` as 'item_id',
            o.`invoice_id` as 'invoice_id_on_items',
            o.`name` as 'program',
            o.`value` as 'fee',
            o.`amount` as 'qty',
            o.`desc` as 'forweek',
            group_concat( o.`desc` separator ' & ' ) as 'forweekgroup',          
            round( sum( ( o.`value` ) * ( o.`amount` ) ),2 ) as 'inv-total'
            from `o70vm_invoices_items` o
            where o.`invoice_id` = '$invoiceid';";


    // storing the result of this MySQL query
    $resultItems = mysql_query( $queryItems );
    if( $resultItems ){
        echo '
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Program</th>
                    <th scope="col">fee</th>
                </tr>';

        $id=0; /* Each field / element that has an id must have a unique id ~ use a counter to achieve this */
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $resultItems ) ){

            $id++;/* Increment the id counter */

            echo '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row->item_id.'</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" title="'.$row->program.'" name="name" id="name'.$id.'" value="' . $row->program. '" />
                    </td>
                    <td>'.$row->fee.'</td>
                </tr>';
        }

        echo '
            </table>';
    } else {/* Do not give away too much information and degrade gracefully */
        echo 'Sorry, there was an error retrieving relevant information from the database';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Looks like if I just add a GROUP BY o.id in the MySQL Statement, it works. . . WOW . . . Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Your query contains these two lines. Together they guarantee you'll get only one row in your resultset.

```
WHERE    o70vm_invoices_items.invoice_id = $invoiceID
GROUP BY o70vm_invoices_items.invoice_id
```

Your WHERE line filters your table so the resultset only contains rows for a particular `invoice_id` value.  Then, GROUP BY summarizes the information for that particular value in one result-set row.

From your question it sounds like you have multiple items per invoice, and you wish to show detail rows for the items. In that case you're going to need to group by the items, not the `invoice_id`.

Try this GROUP BY.

```
 GROUP BY  o70vm_invoices_items.id
```

And, you are using a very confusing nonstandard MySQL extension to the `GROUP BY` functionality.  If you start working with more than one table, this will bite you hard. Read about it. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html